# Invalid RegEx Entered by User in Django Form Causes 500 Server Error

Tags: python, regex, django, forms

I have a simple Django search form set up in my web application, where users can search for particular words in my Arabic corpus. The users can search one of three way: 'Exact' (the word just as it's typed), 'Stem' (which brings up all inflected forms of the lemma entered), and 'RegEx' (where they can do more complex searches by regular expression).

The problem I'm having is, if the user submits an invalid regex, instead of giving them a validation error or empty results, it triggers a 500 server error. Which I imagine is confusing. Below is the traceback for such and error, caused by searching for a regex with unbalanced parenthesis: ha((.*(?!al))

Is there anyway to catch this kind of error, or make it more user-friendly? (I've also included the code for my form below.)

Thank you.

```
class ConcordanceForm(forms.Form):
    searchterm = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    search_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), 
             choices= ([('string', 'Exact'), ('lemma', 'Stem'), ('regex', 'Regex') ]),
             required=True )


def concord_test(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = ConcordanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            searchterm = form.cleaned_data['searchterm'].encode('utf-8')
            search_type = form.cleaned_data['search_type']
            context, texts_len, results_len = make_concordance(searchterm, search_type)
            return render_to_response('corpus/concord.html', locals())
    else:
        form = ConcordanceForm()
    return render_to_response('corpus/search_test.html', 
                              {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



<p style=" font-weight:bold;">Search for any word in the corpus:</p>
<form action="/search_test/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/tunisiya2/corpus/views.py", line 154, in concord_test
    context, texts_len, results_len = make_concordance(searchterm, search_type)

  File "/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/tunisiya2/corpus/views.py", line 91, in make_concordance
    p = re.compile(r'\b' + searchterm + r'__') # initial position in word_pos_lemma string

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression

error: unbalanced parenthesis


<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'searchterm': [u'ha((.*(?!al))'], u'search_type': [u'regex'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'c9a6cad4a0761580f5e351e9e534e028']}>,
COOKIES:{'__utma': '58037167.1544119768.1401037185.1401381302.1401384825.14',
 '__utmb': '58037167.10.10.1401384825',
 '__utmc': '58037167',
 '__utmz': '58037167.1401037185.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'csrftoken': 'c9a6cad4a0761580f5e351e9e534e028',
 'sessionid': '8d5b0b8730ccce0860b687b4c7ec1fdb'},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '109',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'c9a6cad4a0761580f5e351e9e534e028',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'sessionid=8d5b0b8730ccce0860b687b4c7ec1fdb; csrftoken=c9a6cad4a0761580f5e351e9e534e028; __utma=58037167.1544119768.1401037185.1401381302.1401384825.14; __utmb=58037167.10.10.1401384825; __utmc=58037167; __utmz=58037167.1401037185.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'HTTP_FORWARDED_REQUEST_URI': '/search_test/',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.tunisiya.org',
 'HTTP_HTTPS': 'off',
 'HTTP_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://www.tunisiya.org',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.tunisiya.org/search_test/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '68.9.41.110',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'www.tunisiya.org',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER': 'www.tunisiya.org',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL': 'off',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/search_test/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/tunisiya2.wsgi/search_test/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '37086',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/search_test/',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/tunisiya2.wsgi',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': '[no address given]',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.tunisiya.org',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.8',
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'tunisiya2.com|',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '39877',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': '',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 2),
 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0xd69b570>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0xa7efda0>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0xd69b598>,


 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to read up on [handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).  In this case, you would want to catch the error, "humanize it" (i.e., say "Invalid expression entered), and return a page with no results and the error.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `make_concordance` in `try`-`except`; if an exception occurs, 
render the original form template for the user, along with the error information.

```
import re
try:
    context, texts_len, results_len = make_concordance(searchterm, search_type)
except re.error as e:
    form._errors['search_term'] = str(e)
    del form.cleaned_data['search_term']

    return render_to_response('corpus/search_test.html', 
         {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

The better way could be to make a [custom cleaner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute), but it seems to be a bit more complicated, and I do not have Django.

Comment: Thank you Antti, I think this is just what I need. I had problems implementing your second solutions, so I've just added the try/except, and it works! If I put in an invalid regex, it stays on the form instead of trying to process it and returning a server error.

Comment: I still have one problem: what to do in the space where you've written "# report str(e) as an error to the user". How do I get an error message to display on the form? (I'm sorry, I know this is probably obvious, but I'm not very experienced working with forms.)

Comment: what problems there are with the second solution? It should readily display the error for the user automatically

Comment: There were a lot. I spent about half an hour solving them one by one, but gave up when I got to: 
  File "/home/larapsodia/webapps/django/tunisiya2/corpus/models.py", line 25, in clean_searchterm
    self.cleaned_data['search_type'])

KeyError: 'search_type'

Comment: I think the first is better for me, because it's simpler and I have a better understanding of it. Can you tell me how to pass the error message through to the form?

Comment: Ok, django validators work worse than I thought, how about the code I just edited there?

Comment: Stays on the page, but no message is displayed.

Comment: which django version is this

Comment: 1.3 ... I know, it's old and unsupported, but I don't have time to upgrade my whole application.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do a custom cleaner after all. I'm trying to implement that now, based on the docs, but having issues. I'll post it as a separate question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building a custom cleaner, as Antti mentioned. This is what worked in the end:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    searchterm = cleaned_data.get('searchterm')
    search_type = cleaned_data.get('search_type')
    if search_type == 'regex':
        try:
            re.search(searchterm, 'randomdatastring') #this is just to test if the regex is valid
        except re.error:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid regular expression.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Sam's comment, here's how to capture the specific error when a regular expression fails to compile:

```
import re
err_message = None
try:
    re.compile('(unbalanced')
except re.error as exc:
    err_message = 'Uhoh: {}'.format(exc)

print err_message
```

Output:

> Uhoh: unbalanced parenthesis

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to catch the exception in this way, but my problem with your solution (and with the docs Sam referenced) is that I'm not doing this on the command line: I need to know how to return the error message to the form.